# Unit test using jasmine for durandal router

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, single-page-application, durandal

I am using durandal framework for my Single Page Application. Where i need to test a function using jasmine.
The following router.js function code throwing error.

```
router.navigateTo("#/Home/About");
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'sammy.lookupRoute')
```

I tried to fix this issue by registering routes in my specs

```
            router.mapNav("reports/create");
            router.mapNav("reports/display");
```

Still am getting same error. How to fix this issue? Is there any example for testing router.js modules.